# Column (XIT115) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined)

Tags: java, database, eclipse, informix

I am getting below error when running this informix update statement using Eclipse. The same query runs absolutely fine when it is run using DBeaver tool.

```
Update logistics_user_security:informix.user set password_expiry_ts = Today-1 where user_id = "XIT115"
```

Error observer in eclipse in below :

```
Column (XIT115) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined).];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your client configuration in Eclipse is probably setting the `DELIMIDENT` environment variable. That means that the strings inside double quotation marks ( " ) are interpreted as SQL identifiers. Use single quotation marks ( `'` ) for literal strings or change the `DELIMIDENT` environment variable.

Link to the official documentation: [The DELIMIDENT Environment Variable](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1614.htm)